# Can I have Sticky Note of Microsoft on Ubuntu?

Tags: 22.04

Because that app have save my note on cloud so I can open it from anywhere. So I really want it on my Ubuntu OS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Microsoft sticky notes are actually saved on OneNote, and you can view and edit sticky notes on the web by going to [www.onenote.com/stickynotes](http://www.onenote.com/stickynotes). If you have an Outlook email address associated with your account, the notes are also viewable in a folder in your emails, but they aren't editable from there.

These notes will not be able to "stick" on your desktop the way they do on Windows. If you want to use a sticky notes application that works the way Microsoft Sticky Notes does on Windows, it will not be able to sync with your Microsoft sticky notes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!